# prove that $SF:FD=1:2$

Tags: vectors

Given a Pyramid $ABCDS$ with Parallelogram $ABCD$ as a base.

The diagonals of a parallelogram intersect in point $O$.

$\vec{SA}=u,\: \vec{SB}=v,\:\vec{SC}=w,\:\vec{SF}=k\cdot\vec{SD} ,\:\vec{SE}=t\cdot\vec{SO},\: SE=EO$.

Prove that point $F$ is dividing $SD$ in ratio of $SF:FD=1:2$.

$B,E,F$ is on the same line.

I tried analytic approach but got stuck

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the analytic approach, and just where you got stuck?

Comment: yes, i tried to place the pyramid on a Cartesian coordinate system and started to calculate the lengths.